# Boot problems when adding new hard drive to working 18.04 system

Tags: boot, partitioning, mount, hard-drive, fdisk

I have a ubuntu 18.04 system with 3 spinning hard drives, (sda, sdb, and sdc), that has been working fine. Tonight, I just added a 4th drive, (3TB WD blue), currently unformatted and unpartitioned, but now the system won't boot to the GUI, but stays in the emergency maintenance mode.

I was expecting it to name the new drive as sdd, and then let me partition and format it. But it fails the file system check on sdc -- and when looking at the output from fdisk -l, I realize that it has decided to name the new blank drive as sdc.

What's the best way around problems like this, would moving sata cables around make it better? I could also edit my fstab, and comment out the mounting of sdc.

Seems like there should be an accepted way to add a new hard disk to a system without causing problems.

Comment: I'm surprised your fstab uses block device names like /dev/sdXY - afaik Ubuntu has used UUIDs for some time for exactly the reasons you are encountering

Comment: The drive letters (sda, sdb, sdc etc) are controlled by your hardware & firmware, not Ubuntu.  That's why UUIDs are used (so a BIOS/uEFI setting change doesn't screw things up, or adding/removing drives etc). I'd also check your PSU is good/reliable, as drive issues can occur on addition of another *heavy power-drawing* unit like a *spinning-rust* drive...  and it may be struggling with the extra drive and causing your issues...

Comment: The best way around this is to use UUIDs in fstab but you can probably work round it for now by swapping the cables of the old sdc and the new disk. Swap the socket they are plugged into on the motherboard

Comment: What SATA port did you use? Normally the devices are in SATA port order. There may be some limits on ports, check your manual. If you have Asmedia ports, do not use them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As several of you noted, the best answer is to stop using sda,sdb,sdc,sdd in fstab, and use the UUID's.

The quick answer that solved it for me was to comment out the mounting of sdc -- that allowed the gui to start.

But I believe the long term answer is to use UUIDs in the fstab.